# How to check whether a user is logged into his google account through API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am developing a page to show preview of documents accessible to a user.

For previewing I am using an Iframe with src = https://docs.google.com/viewer?authuser=0&srcid={a document id}

The problem here is that when the user is not logged in it shows a blank iframe.

I want to redirect the user to google login page if the current user is not logged in and then display the page previewing the document.

For this functionality I will have to check first that whether the user is logged in with google or not.

I think google has some restrictions imposed in case of iframe so it not redirecting to the login page.

How can I implement it through API?

Answer (score 0):

If you use App Engine do it like this:

To view the page which is showing the google doc must already be checking if you are logged in.

Just configure the Google Users-API.  Everything is described here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/overview

And set the security constraints in web.xml
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Security_and_Authentication

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/page_shows_google_doc</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: Sam > I am working on Force.com platform, so I cannot make use of Java API. The view page that I am using redirects to google's service login page but the request gets aborted. Is it because I am embedding it in an IFrame? Since when I try the same url in the browser it redirects me to the login page.

Comment: Then you why are you marking this with Google App Engine? :-) You should write that in the Question. I don't know how it works on force.com

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I just wanted to know the API for implementing this which can be used with any platform after authorization.

Comment: No worries :-) I add "salesforce" or "force" for you to the tag-list.

Comment: Yeah will do that. Thanks for answering.

Comment: After some study I realised that we cannot make use of an iframe with a src to google's login page. Actually google restricts the use of iframes for many of it's pages by setting the header "X-Frame-Options".