# Is user logged into Google?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check whether a user is logged into his google account through API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459720/how-to-check-whether-a-user-is-logged-into-his-google-account-through-api)

I am developing a webpage that shows a Google Calendar.

My question is this: Is it possible to detect if a user is currently logged into a Google Account? If it is possible (I am pretty sure that it is), what is the easiest way to detect this?

Comment: similar / same question with a very quick search

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459720/how-to-check-whether-a-user-is-logged-into-his-google-account-through-api

Comment: you can check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202785/detect-if-a-web-user-is-currently-logged-in-google)

Answer (score 0):

User should allow you to do this. You should use Google API, here it is:
http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/

Check the APIs, signup for API key and users should let you to check their status in Google.

Comment: See here:http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/detect-visitor-social-networks/#code  It's all in one code to check user's status in Facebook, Google, Twitter, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked the Google developer guide? https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth recommends OAuth 2.0.